Creating a frame with text ON the line
Hello to all (please excuse my English, I'lm French...)
I'm just starting with LaTeX and I'm trying to create the structure of my future documents (physics & chemistry lessons).
I'm going for article class (one lesson at a time, so no chapters) and I want to create a box with text INCLUDED ON the upper line of the box.
I've found this code to format the title of chapters :
\titleformat
    {\chapter}                          
        [frame]
        {\normalsize}
        {\filright\large\quad\begin{cursive}Chapitre O\&S 02-1\end{cursive}\quad}
        {18pt}
        {\huge\bfseries\filcenter}`

(Chapter is named "Signaux et capteurs")
I get exactly the graphical result I would like (title inside a box and the box as the reference number on it), but since it is a chapter and I dont want chapters in my document (problems with the table of contents), I'd like to find a code to have the same result, but for plain text (I don't know if I'm really clear...)
enter image description here
On the image, up is what I want (I get it with \titleformat), down is what I have with :
\filright\large\quad\begin{cursive}Chapitre O\&S 02-1\end{cursive}\quad 

\fbox
    {\fboxrule=2pt
    \fboxsep=6pt
    \begin{minipage}[c][30mm][c]{16cm}
        \huge\bfseries\filcenter\uuline{Signaux et Capteurs 2}
    \end{minipage}}


In case you prefer to ask in French: https://texnique.fr/osqa/
